# Oracle SQL to find population by percentage range

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table with customers, purchase date and zip code. Key is (customer_id, purchase_dt and zip_cd)

I am trying to find zip codes where customers are doing business, ranges like 80% and above, 60 - 80%, 40-60%. Can someone help me out with a query to achieve this.

```
with tmp as
(
    select 123 as cust_id, date '2017-01-01' purchase_dt, '10035' zip_cd from dual
    union
    select 1234 as cust_id, date '2019-06-01' purchase_dt, '11377' zip_cd from dual
    union
    select 12345 as cust_id, date '2019-07-01' purchase_dt, '11377' zip_cd from dual
    union
    select 234 as cust_id, date '2019-08-01' purchase_dt, '11377' zip_cd from dual
    union
    select 2345 as cust_id, date '2019-09-01' purchase_dt, '11417' zip_cd from dual

)
select * from tmp;
```

Expected output:

80% and above zip code: 11377 and so on..

Answer (score 0):

You can use the combination of the `average` and `analytical function count` as follows:

```
with tmp as
(
    select 123 as cust_id, date '2017-01-01' purchase_dt, '10035' zip_cd from dual
    union
    select 1234 as cust_id, date '2019-06-01' purchase_dt, '11377' zip_cd from dual
    union
    select 12345 as cust_id, date '2019-07-01' purchase_dt, '11377' zip_cd from dual
    union
    select 234 as cust_id, date '2019-08-01' purchase_dt, '11377' zip_cd from dual
    union
    select 2345 as cust_id, date '2019-09-01' purchase_dt, '11417' zip_cd from dual

)
select zip_cd, 100*(count(1)/cnt) percntg from
(select zip_cd, count(1) over () cnt from tmp)
group by zip_cd, cnt
order by percntg desc;
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer will take into account if a customer has made purchases on multiple days and won't double count them.  Additionally, this response adds in the grouping discussed in the question:

```sql
with tmp as
(
    select 123 as cust_id, date '2017-01-01' purchase_dt, '10035' zip_cd from dual
    union
    select 1234 as cust_id, date '2019-06-01' purchase_dt, '11377' zip_cd from dual
    union
    select 12345 as cust_id, date '2019-07-01' purchase_dt, '11377' zip_cd from dual
    union
    select 234 as cust_id, date '2019-08-01' purchase_dt, '11377' zip_cd from dual
    union
    select 2345 as cust_id, date '2019-09-01' purchase_dt, '11417' zip_cd from dual

)
SELECT sub2.pct_range, listagg(sub2.zip_cd||' ('||sub2.zip_pct||')', ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY zip_pct DESC) AS ZIP_CODES
FROM (SELECT CASE
               WHEN sub.zip_pct BETWEEN 80 AND 100 THEN '80% and above'
               WHEN sub.zip_pct BETWEEN 60 AND 79 THEN '60% to 79%'
               WHEN sub.zip_pct BETWEEN 40 AND 59 THEN '40% to 59%'
               WHEN sub.zip_pct BETWEEN 20 AND 39 THEN '20% to 39%'
               ELSE 'Below 20%' 
             END AS PCT_RANGE,
             sub.zip_cd,
             sub.zip_pct
      FROM (SELECT DISTINCT 
              zip_cd, 
              100*COUNT(DISTINCT cust_id) OVER (PARTITION BY zip_cd)/COUNT(DISTINCT cust_id) OVER () AS ZIP_PCT
            FROM tmp) sub) sub2
GROUP BY pct_range
ORDER BY pct_range DESC;
```